# Select from 3 tables php

Tags: mysql, join

at first sorry for my bad english, but i need to do a table with GET method to select data of 3 tables

```
where $_GET['steamid']: 
achievements (id, name, description);
progress (id_player, achieve_id, progress);
global (id_player, steamid, nick);

to put in a table, example:
Achievement | Progress 
name_achievement | 5
```

like at: http://achievements.my-run.de/index.php?server=jail

Comment: Just do a join select of the 3 tables. And elaborate your question, write proper php code maybe :D

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please put more details into your question? We can't help you with this poor information. Also, please tell us what you tried so far. SO is not a coding service. You should be aware of that.

Comment: i need to know how to use the join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a [`join`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) to join your tables into one query. I think this should work, just bind the `GET` value.

```
select a.name, p.progress from global as g
join progress as p
on g.id_player = p.id_player
join achievements as a
on p.achieve_id = a.id
where g.steamid = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt understand what you really mean, but something like this maybe?

```
SELECT achievements.id, achievements.name, achievements.description, progress.id_player, progress.archieve_id, progress.progress, global.id_player, global.steamid, global.nick
FROM global INNER JOIN achievements ON global.id_player = achievements.id INNER JOIN progress ON progress.id_player = achievements.id
WHERE global.steamid = STEAMID
```

Comment: I'm not sure there is a correlation between `global.id_player` and `achievements.id`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all, already got
sorry about the mess and for my bad english

i did it:

```
$sql_global = "SELECT Id FROM promad_mglobal WHERE SteamId='".$steam."'";
    $result_global = $con->query($sql_global);
    while($row_global = $result_global->fetch_assoc())
        $idd = $row_global['Id'];

    $sql_medals = "SELECT * FROM promad_medalhas 
    LEFT JOIN promad_mprogresso ON (promad_mprogresso.Achievement = promad_medalhas.Id AND promad_mprogresso.Id='$idd')";

    $result_medals = $con->query($sql_medals);
    while($row_medals = $result_medals->fetch_assoc())
    {       
        if(empty($row_medals['Progress']))
            $row_medals['Progress'] = 0;

        echo "- ".$row_medals['Name']." ".$row_medals['Progress']." <br>";
    }
```

and it works!

thanks